# Typeahead.js call ASP.Net core API

Tags: c#, asp.net, typeahead.js

I want to use typeahead.js to my autocomplete search bar. I have an API which return a list of subjects. Now I want to use that API for typeahead.

I have checked my API and it works. It seems I have problems with AJAX but I can not figure it out what's wrong?

```
$('#inputSearch').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:59602/api/subject",
                data: "{'prefix': '" + request + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    items = [];
                    map = {};
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        var id = item.id;
                        var name = item.name;
                        map[name] = { id: id, name: name };
                        items.push(name);
                    });
                    response(items);

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

My search bar

```
 <div class="col">
                        <input asp-for="subjectID" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-borderless" type="text" placeholder="Search subject"
                               id="inputSearch" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
```

Comment: I didn't look closely at all but as I looked down i saw in the input `autocomplete="off"`. should that be on?

Comment: It does not work too

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: I dont see any error. It just not show data in the input. For example, when I type 's' it must show 'SWT', 'SSS'...but now it is showing anything

Comment: So? Did you debug it? Log the response from the API? Step through the code? Look for errors in the JS console? These are basic troubleshooting steps you need to perform.

Comment: Did you get data back from your API? Pl check if it returns 'SWT', 'SSS' when for your key value 's'.

Comment: Look like you're missing ', updater: function ( item )' Have a look at http://embed.plnkr.co/EXP0JTP11aiw8JpcdFFh

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quick look at the docs and it looks like you need two objects inside `.typeahead`.

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({   // <- typeahead settings.
  minLength: 3,
  highlight: true
},                            // <- comma + new object below for data.
{
  name: 'my-dataset',
  source: mySource            // <- put your source here.
});
```

hth.